# Can A* with an inadmissible heuristic still be optimal?

Tags: search-algorithms, heuristics

It is clear to me that if some heuristic $h(x)$ is admissible, then $A^*$ is guaranteed to find a least-cost path. But is it also possible that $A^*$ is optimal if $h(x)$ is not admissible? In other words, should this be an if and only if relation?

One example that I am considering is graphs in the Euclidean plane. Instead of directly using the Euclidean distance, multiply it by a factor $\alpha > 1$
$$
h(x) = \alpha \cdot \sqrt{(x_1 - t_1)^2 + (x_2 - t_2)^2}
$$
where $x=(x_1,x_2)$ is an arbitrary node and $t=(t_1,t_2)$ is the target node.

Let $h^*(x)$ be the true minimal cost from $x$ to $t$.
Suppose there is some node $a$ that is directly connected to $t$ and that that edge has length 3. Then $h(a)>h^*(a)=3$ and then $h(x)$ is not admissible.

It looks to me like $A^*$ should still be optimal in this case, but I do not have a proof of which I am conviced yet. Is it?

Comment: It doesn't matter on path graphs.